# What service uses UDP port 495?

Tags: networking, port

I am investigating some interesting traffic that I picked up using `tcpdump`. I received 500+ UDP/IP packets from source `port 495`.

[IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) has assigned that port to `intecourier`. If I search for `port 495` on Google, every result lists `intecourier` as both the service and description. Can anyone define `intecourier`?

Comment: Good question, you could email sfavor@tigger.intecom.com as he is the contact & assignee of that port/service per IANA

Comment: Keeping in mind that a port can be used by any process, it is often best to identify the process that is generating/consuming the traffic (though if you are sitting in the middle, without access to the endpoints, that is a bit of a problem), or hope that the traffic itself contains data that tells you more about what it is. if you have a pcap of it, there are likely tools out there that could identify the data layout, if its well known. I'd start with wireshark.

Comment: Source port is rarely relevant.  That just happens to be what the remote device was sending from.  The real question is: **what was the destination port** because that will be a stronger hint about what the service remote side was trying to initiate contact with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of old well-known-port registrations are for proprietary protocols from companies that have long since gone defunct, such as "intecourier" from "intecom.com" (note: no 'r'). According to the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine, they sold enterprise telephone equipment up until about 2003, when they sold out to "EADS Telecom", which also no longer exists.

Whatever traffic you're seeing, is almost certainly not whatever "intecourier" was.

Someone is probably just squatting on an unused port, or maybe that traffic came through a poorly-implemented NAT gateway that didn't know better than to remap traffic to come from low port numbers.